# How does cheat engine determine if a memory address is static?(In a programmatic way)

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I have done some research on determining if an address is static. Someone from StackOverflow suggests that I could do it by monitor all memory allocations. But I guess that ISN'T how Cheat Engine because CE does not need to start prior to the game. A static address is the address that the content inside does not change across different runs of a program. EX. If the address 0x400000 stores a character's health in a game and that address is static, health value is always stored in that address even if you restart the game.      Wikipedia definition:

```
 "Static memory allocation is the allocation of memory at compile-time before the associated program is executed,"
```

typically, address of functions are static as well as global variables. Someone in another post said:

```
 ".data section, in which the .exe stores the address offset for the section so Cheat Engine just checks if the variable is in this address range (from this section to the next one)."
```

That approach might be able to check for global variables. But what about the code section?

ps: address returned by any memory allocation function like `VirtualAlloc` is dynamic. Another example of static address is the "Base address" when hacking games.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "static" memory address? This question seems like it starts in the middle of your thought process. You haven't given us enough information to go on here.

Comment: Static and dynamic memory are from different parts of the address range. By looking at an address you can make a pretty good guess on what part it comes from.

Comment: But I want a way to accurately determine if an address is static, not just a guess. @BoPersson

Comment: `If the address 0x400000 stores a character's health in a game and that address is static, health value is always stored in that address even if you restart the game.` This is false in the general case. For example, a global variable declared in a DLL that the main EXE uses is not guaranteed to have the same memory address between 2 runs.

Comment: Agree. But in that case the address is NOT static. A static address has to be static. @dxiv

Comment: You wrote `typically, address of functions are static as well as global variables`. Both of those can be relocated if they are in a DLL, and the DLL does not load at its preferred address (or is manually rebased). Guess what you mean by `static` is more commonly known as `fixed`.

Comment: "typically" doesn't imply always, but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: None of these things are actually static, even "typically". Dynamic address relocation is very common, especially on modern software. Often done by the operating system. You can't expect to get something loaded at the same address *across multiple executions*. Properly designed software doesn't rely on items being stored at specific memory addresses, and you shouldn't either.